# Debbuging no node js

Tags: node.js, debug

Como faço para voltar o debug do vscode para o padrão do node para ver as variaveis e os breakpoints no lado do servidor? Por que executei uma vez o debbuger for chrome e agora ele nem pergunta mais qual ambiente ele vai debugar. É importante pra mim pq sou iniciante e entendo melhor o código debugando.

Answer (score 0):

Guilherme, você precisa alterar a forma que o VSCode vai depurar o programa.

---

Esse é um exemplo de **launch.json** para depurar tanto com o chrome quanto com o node:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Node",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\teste.js"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

O seu launch.json deve ter ao menos a configuração do chrome, talvez já tenha ambas, então nem precisa se preocupar com ele caso já possua as configurações necessárias.

> Ambas as configurações o próprio VSCode criou pra mim conforme eu
>   executei o arquivo teste.js

---

Agora é só alterar a forma que o VSCode vai depurar, para isso clique no ícone de debug no menu lateral esquerdo:

[image: Ícone de debug]

Estando então na visão de debug, basta alterar a forma de depuração, isso é feito no combobox superior:

[image: Opções de depuração]

*Obs.:* Essas opções presentes no combobox são as mesmas presentes no seu launch.json.

> Nesse mesmo combobox, você pode selecionar a opção de adicionar nova
>   configuração, com isso selecionar o tipo de debug que deseja, na
>   listagem, você vai encontrar node e também chrome.

---

Comment: Tentei configurar o meu VSC para fazer o debugger pelo Chrome ... usei a configuração do  launch.json  semelhante a que voce sugeriu, apenas mudando a pra 3000 ... e quando aperto F5  da uma pensada e não abre o Chrome.... saberia me dizer por quê ?  OBS.: Tirei a configuração do Node ...deixei somente a do Chroem

Comment: Não sei dizer, uso essa configuração até hoje, trocando apenas a porta conforme necessidade, verifica se ele gerou algum log.

Comment: Sim bem estranho... nada acontece, até ameaça iniciar mas em momento algum o Chrome abre.

Comment: Tem como 'resetar' (voltar as configurações originais ) do VSCODE ? ai depois eu instalaria todas as extensões novamente.  Será que isso pode resolver ?

Comment: Não sei se resolve, mas caso queira fazer, as configurações do VSCode são salvas na pasta do usuário ```seuUsuario/.vscode```, pode tentar também apagar as configurações da Workspace, que é a pasta ```.vscode``` de onde você está trabalhando.